# VSCode: How to use Chromium for debugging on local files (extension: Debugger for Chrome )

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, chromium, vscode-debugger

My goal is to properly set `launch.json` file to run some *.html in Chromium.

For example: This is my project folder structure:

```
project/
├─ some_folder/
│  ├─ index.html
│  ├─ script.js
├─ index.html
├─ script.js
```

In the end I'd like to create configurations for both `index.html` files.

Extension page: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=msjsdiag.debugger-for-chrome

- Ubuntu 20.04
- VSCodium 1.55.1

It has to be possible to use Chromium instead of Chrome using `runtimeExecutable` (and some `runtimeArgs` if needed) in `launch.json`

So I tried:

```js
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Launch index.html",
            "type": "chrome",
            "request": "launch",
            "file": "${workspaceFolder}/index.html",
            "runtimeExecutable": "/usr/bin/chromium-browser",
            "runtimeArgs": [
              "--new-window",
              "--user-data-dir=\"/${workspaceFolder}/DevProfile\"",
              "--remote-debugging-port=9222",
              "--disable-background-networking"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I tried same without or with some of `runtimeArgs`. Also tried`${fileWorkspaceFolder}` or `${fileFolder}` or `index.html` absolute path instead `${workspaceFolder}`.

Still same result - Chromium doesn't even start. No error, nothing. Only some kind of progressbar shortly showed  in `RUN AND DEBUG` window.

I'm out of ideas. Thanks for help!

Comment: I bet this to be wrong path -> "runtimeExecutable": "/usr/bin/chromium-browser". A common value is /usr/bin/chromium. Search yours with `which chromium`. I tried and works, way better than start browser manually.

Answer (score 1):

*Note: As of a year after the question was posted, the extension mentioned is deprecated.*

You can try starting chromium with remote debugging enabled, then setting the launch.json configuration to attach to the remote debugging port.

Start chromium like this:

`/usr/bin/chromium-browser --remote-debugging-port=9222 --user-data-dir=remote-debug-profile`

And your launch.config should look like this:

```
{
  "configurations": [
    {
      "type": "pwa-chrome",
      "request": "attach",
      "name": "Attach to browser",
      "port": 9222
    }
  ]
}
```

Summarizing VS Code's documentation on this:

> To attach to a running browser, it needs to be launched in a special debug mode.

> ...

> Setting the `--remote-debugging-port` tells the browser to listen on that port for a debug connection. Setting a separate `--user-data-dir` forces a new instance of the browser to be opened; if this flag isn't given, then the command will open a new window of any running browser and not enter debug mode.

Source: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/nodejs/browser-debugging#_attaching-to-browsers